# Displaying the same page, no matter what URI

Tags: redirects, iis

We have moved a webapplication and would like to display a message in the old IIS. Let's say that the application was in `http://oldserver/appname/`. How do I make sure that our `moved.html` is displayed to the user no matter which uri the user browsed in to (in that virtual folder)?

- http://oldserver/appname/some/path.aspx ---> should display `http://oldserver/appname/moved.html`
- http://oldserver/appname --> should display `http://oldserver/appname/moved.html`

Comment: Suggestion: Consider just using the 301 redirect suggested by Nathaniel bellow, without the message. Search engines will transfer pagerank (or similar indicator) to the new URL. With a message that might not happen. Search engines will think the content was deleted and will not transfer it to the new URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a 301 redirect:

http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/windows-server-2008-http-redirection